# ArrayList of Hashmaps not showing in Android listview

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, adapter

I am trying to populate a listview with an arraylist of Hashmaps (String, Integer). I'm not getting have any errors however the list does not show anything. I have looked at other questions similar to this but in those cases they did not have any data in their arraylists. From the logcat i can see the list is present but the view isn't showing. Any idea how to resolve this?

CODE :

```
public class JsonActivity extends ListActivity{

 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // JSON Node names

    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_ARTISTNAME = "artistname";

 // chartItemList is the array list that holds the chart items 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> chartItemList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, 
        Integer>>();
    JsonParser Parser = new JsonParser();
 // JSONArray
    JSONArray chartItems = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);

        //url from where the JSON has to be retrieved
        String url = "http://web.com/test.php";

        //Check if the user has a connection

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (!info.isConnected()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your connection and try again.", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //if positive, fetch the articles in background
            else new getChartItems().execute(url);
        }

        //else show toast
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your connection and try again.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    class getChartItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Shows a progress dialog while executing background task
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(JsonActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading chart...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        //Gets the json data for chart items data and presents it in a list view
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String url = "http://web.com/test.php";
            String json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            int id;

            String artistname;

            try{

            chartItems = new JSONArray(json);

            JSONObject json_data=null;

             for(int i=0;i<chartItems.length();i++){

                json_data = chartItems.getJSONObject(i);

                artistname=json_data.getString("artistname");
                id=json_data.getInt("id");


                 HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                 // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    hashMap.put(artistname,id);

                 // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                    chartItemList.add(hashMap);

             }


              ;
            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     System.out.println(chartItemList);
                  //updating list view with the parsed items

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JsonActivity.this, chartItemList,
                            R.layout.listview,
                            new String[] {TAG_ARTISTNAME,TAG_ID }, new int[] 

                         {R.id.artistname,R.id.id });
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
            return null;
        }

        //Removes the progress dialog when the data has been fetched
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }


 }
```

VIEW :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">  
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#eee">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff0a0a"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artistname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but why are you using `runOnUiThread()` then returning null when `onPostExecute()` already runs in the UI Thread? If you'd return the List instead of null in `doInBackground()`, you could use `onPostExecute()` like it's meant to be used.

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast is you layout file name is `progressdialog` ?

Comment: @A--C : i agree with u, OP need to move UI related part inside onPostExecute from doInBackground

Comment: @PratikSharma i have two layout files, one called list_view and the other is progress dialog

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast can you post your `list_view` xml content?

Comment: @PratikSharma listview xml is shown above.

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast : try to change your current AsyncTask class [as](http://pastebin.com/LxrBhKa4)

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast see the solution I have posted below. I think that is the only problem with your code.

Comment: @PratikSharma thanks that works, i was trying to create a chart where id is the rank of the artist and artistname. I changed the integers to strings so it works now. Thanks a lot everyone :)

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast you are always welcome. If it helps you to solve your problem then you can accept my solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line :

```
// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
 hashMap.put(artistname,id);
```

**with this,**

```
// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
 hashMap.put(TAG_ARTISTNAME, artistname);
 hashMap.put(TAG_ID, id);
```

**HashMap** will store values in **key=>value** pairs only.